# Javascript and XPath: not loading all matches of tag

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm creating a XML template and then I will load into my JS code. I'm having trouble loading all instances of a tag. In this example, `<section>`:

```
let xmltemplate = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<sheet>
    <meta>
    <version>0</version>
    <author></author>
    <contact></contact>
    <notes></notes>
    <released></released>
    <updated></updated>
    </meta>
    <section name="section 1"></section>
    <section name="section 2"></section>
</sheet>`;


var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xmltemplate, 'text/xml');
let nodes = xmlDoc.evaluate("//section", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result = nodes,iterateNext();
console.log(result);
```

The console just shows the first section, not both:

```
<section name="section 1"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What does running `var result = nodes.iterateNext();` after `console.log` (then running `console.log` on `result`) give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate in a `while` loop :

```
var node = null;
while ( node = nodes.iterateNext()) {
  console.log(node)
}
```